# How to search the column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
Values

9A 200x400x600
10B 400x200x500
....
```

Values Column datatype is nvarchar

Query

```
Select * from table1 where values like '" & textbox1.text & "%'
```

The above query is working, but I want to search in 4 ways

I want to search a column with every 3 digit

The query should not check `space` and `x` values from the column.

Expected Output

- if I type in textbox1 9A or 10A the query should return first 2 or 3 values
- If I type in textbox2 200 or 400 the query should return 200 from first row or 400 from second row
- If I type in textbox3 400 or 200 the query should return 400 from first row or 200 from second row
- If I type in textbox4 600 or 500 the query should return 600 from first row and 500 from second row

How to split the column value for search

Need query help

Comment: You mean you want to type in "200 or 400" or "200" or "400". If the latter?

Comment: @gbn, Yes i want to type the value separately

Comment: Are those **two columns** (or just one?) in your table (not clear from your question....)?? What datatypes??

Comment: @marc_s Values Column Datatype is nvarchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know the query is a the question is a bit confused. I will try, let me know if this is close that you are looking for.

I assume that:

```
9A 200x400x600  -> 200x400x600 are de 3*2+2 lasts characters.
10B 400x200x500 -> CHARINDEX(' ', value ) = 4
```

Then, the query is:

```
Select 
     * 
from table1 
where 
   substring( values, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', value ) ) = '" & textbox1.text & "' OR
   substring( right( value, 3*2+2), 1, 3 ) = '" & textbox2.text & "' OR
   substring( right( value, 3*2+2), 5, 3 ) = '" & textbox3.text & "' OR
   substring( right( value, 3*2+2), 9, 3 ) = '" & textbox4.text & "'
```

**edited:**

```
select * from
   (Select 
     substring( values, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', value ) ) as split1,
     substring( right( value, 3*2+2), 1, 3 ) as split2,
     substring( right( value, 3*2+2), 5, 3 ) as split3,
     substring( right( value, 3*2+2), 9, 3 ) as split4,
     * 
   from table1 ) SplitedTable
where 
   SplitedTable.split1 = '" & textbox1.text & "' OR
   SplitedTable.split2 = '" & textbox2.text & "' OR
   SplitedTable.split3 = '" & textbox3.text & "' OR
   SplitedTable.split4 = '" & textbox4.text & "'
```

Comment: Your Query is working but it is not splitting properly, there was the problem in ( value, 3*2+2), 1, 3 )

Answer (score 1):

Please look into database normalisation, particularly [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

At present, your data field `values` is being used to hold multiple different values in a single row - eg. `9A 200x400x600`. (Not only that, but you are also using different value delimiters in the same field, as both  and `x` are being used to delimit fields.)

SQL is not designed for this sort of manipulation.

While it would be possible to produce a query that would return the relevant values, such a query would be unwieldy and inflexible. I therefore suggest normalising the data structure, to be more suitable for querying.

Comment: Hi Marck. I match with your opinion. I don't down vote your answer but  I think that your post should be a comment and not an answer. You presuppose that the user don't know what is normalization and [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). You don't know why this table has this structure.

Comment: @daniyhp: It doesn't matter *why* the table has this structure, it is wrong. Since the user has not raised the issue of normalisation, with regards to querying an unnormalised schema, I deduced that he was unfamiliar with it. (If you follow the link in your own comment, it should be apparent that we are not dealing with *denormalised* data.)

Comment: Ok, you are right another time ... But perhaps OP is trying to normalize a table from inherit system or from a device log and because this he has posted this question about how to split non normalized field.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select " & textbox1.text & " as mYSearch,* 
from table1 
where values like '%" & textbox1.text & "%'
```